# Write a Query to find the last day of first job of every employee

Tags: mysql, sql

Write a Query to find the last day of first job of every employee.

Using HR Schema

```
TABLE - job_history 
employee_id  
start_date 
end_date`   
job_id      
department_id
```

i have tried this.This will work assuming dates don't overlap Please suggest any other way.

```
select  employee_id, min(end_date)
from job_history
group by employee_id;
```

Comment: What is wrong with your query?

Comment: Add sample data and expected result

Comment: Assuming the jobs dates don't overlap your query should be OK.

Comment: does this have to be mysql specific?  If not, you could potentially use window functions like `first_value(end_date) over (partition by employee_id order by start_date)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is OK if the job dates never overlap.

If they do, then the following MySQL 8.x query will do:

```
select 
  employee_id,
  end_date
from (
  select
    employee_id,
    start_date,
    end_date,
    row_number() over(partition by employee_id order by start_date) as rn  
  from job_history
) x
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select j.employee_id, j.end_date 
from job_history j
where not exists (
  select 1 from job_history
  where employee_id = j.employee_id and start_date < j.start_date
)
```

or:

```
select j.employee_id, j.end_date 
from job_history j
where j.start_date = (
  select min(start_date) 
  from job_history
  where employee_id = j.employee_id
)
```

If there is a case that an employee started first at the same day 2 different jobs, then these queries will return both end dates since there is no column to distinguish between the 2. But you could get the min end date between them, with

```
select j.employee_id, min(j.end_date)
```

and add:

```
group by j.employee_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the query below:

```sql
SELECT employee_id, 
last_value(end_date)OVER(PARTITION BY 
employee_id) AS last_day, first_value(job_id) 
OVER(PARTITION BY employee_id) AS first_job
FROM job_history;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).